# Periodicity of events

Tags: c#

For example, we have event that will go every 3 month. Event have DateStart, DataEnd and Periodicity.

Help me to write method that return true/false if event will go at specific date.

```
public bool MonthPeriodicityChecker (DateTime start, DateTime end, DateTime dateCheck, int periodicity)
{

}
```

For example, record have:

```
start = 02/23/2012 22:00:00;
end = 12/31/2012 23:30:00;
periodicity = 3;
```

Method must return true when current month = February, May, August, November.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the *specific* question?

Comment: I think the question is, "Can someone write the code for me?"

Comment: I don't know how to check Periodicity.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450482/periodicity-of-events-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is pretty simple:

```
var someDate = DateTime.Now; // could be any date set some other way

if(someDate > end) return false;

var checkDate = start;
while(checkDate < end)
{
    if(checkDate.Month == someDate.Month && checkDate.Year == someDate.Year)
        return true;
    checkDate = checkDate.AddMonths(periodicity);
}

return false;
```

All you're doing is making sure `someDate` isn't past `end` and that the difference in months between the `start` and `someDate` is divisible evenly by the periodicity.

Comment: Thanks, but your code print April as first, but must be February (for example in question)

Comment: I set checkDate as yesterday.

Comment: @user1230307 Now that he's given you an idea, you could try working on it yourself instead. Then you'd understand the logic, and be able to do something similar in the future.

Comment: @user1230307 - You shouldn't be setting checkDate at all. You should only be setting someDate (which is the date you want to check to see if it falls on the given period).

Comment: sorry, it's typo, I assign value to someDate.