# Periodicity of events 2

Tags: c#

My previous question got a lot cons. I will try again, with a code and why it not work.

For example, we have event that will go every 3 month. Event have DateStart, DataEnd and Periodicity.
For example, we have a record:

```
start = 02/23/2012 22:00:00;
end = 12/31/2012 23:30:00;
periodicity = 3;
```

Method must return true when current month = February, May, August, November.

Code:

```
public bool MonthPeriodicityChecker (DateTime start, DateTime end, DateTime dateToCheck, int periodicity)
{
     var monthDiff = dateToCheck.Month - startDate.Month;
     return (monthDiff-1) % periodicity == 0;
}
```

This code return `true` if month in dateToCheck equals April, July, October. It's skip first month.

**UPDATE:**

Damn,  sorry to all.  In the beyond, I have loop that sumulated dates. And this loop start with 1 and add this 1 to `start`. And next date was 24 February. Therefore, the February not prints( there are checks for number(23) of month too) in my program. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: What problems are you encountering with your code? What are you expecting, and what happened instead? Your other question may have been closed because it was more "solve my problem for me" than "help me solve my problem."

Comment: @BryanWatts: The other question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450333/periodicity-of-events

Comment: What was wrong with your conversation with the guy who *gave* you that code?

Comment: @simchona: I was in the middle of answering that question when it was closed. I am trying to nudge the OP into writing questions that can be clearly answered. The question does not have any question marks.

Comment: @BryanWatts I didn't know you had seen the OP's other question; your first comment was a bit more rhetorical than that. Might it help to edit the old one, since this one might be a dupe?

Comment: Also, @user--it might be nice to attribute the code, since you're not the one who wrote it

Comment: @simchona: I didn't actually vote to close the question and I didn't want to give that impression by saying I had seen it. It was closed anyhow, so I didn't get the chance to edit it. I don't want to infer the OP's questions on this post, either, so I'd like them to edit it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to trigger in February, May, August and November, you shouldn't be subtracting one from the difference. Just use:

```
return (monthDiff % periodicity) == 0;
```

When the months are equal (February), `0 % 3 == 0`. When you're a multiple of three months out (such as August), `6 % 3 == 0`.

And I'm not sure about C# but some languages don't act as you may expect when taking the modulus of a negative number, so I'd be doubly safe with:

```
public bool MonthPeriodicityChecker (DateTime start, DateTime end,
    DateTime dateToCheck, int periodicity)
{
    var monthDiff = dateToCheck.Month - startDate.Month + 12; // make positive
    return (monthDiff % periodicity) == 0;
}
```

However, keep in mind that, because you're only using the month of the year in your calculations, this probably won't work as expected if you run more than 12 months and your periodicity is not something that divides into 12 cleanly.

Example with starting December 2010 for every five months.

- December 2010 is okay since the difference is zero: `0 % 5 == 0`.
- May 2011 is okay since the difference between May and December is five months: `5 % 5 == 0`.
- October 2011 is okay since the difference between October and December is ten months: `10 % 5 == 0`.
- March 2012 is *not* okay. The difference between March and December is three months, not fifteen as has happened in reality: `3 % 5 == 3`.

The upshot of that is that you'll fire in May, October and December in every year.

You can fix that little problem (if it *is* a problem for you) by ensuring the years are taken into account, something like:

```
public bool MonthPeriodicityChecker (DateTime start, DateTime end,
    DateTime dateToCheck, int periodicity)
{
    // assuming Month returns 1-12 here which is the case for C# I think.
    var monthDiff = (dateToCheck.Year * 12 + dateToCheck.Month - 1)
        - (startDate.Year * 12 + startDate.Month - 1);
    return (monthDiff % periodicity) == 0;
}
```

That also gets rid of the need for adding 12 to get a positive number since the advancing years will ensure that (a jump from December to January will now give you 1 rather than -11), assuming that `dateToCheck.Month` will always be greater than or equal to `startDate.Month`.

If there's the possibility that `dateToCheck` may be *less* `startDate`, you probably want to check that first and return false as the first step in the above function.

Answer (score 0):

Your month subtraction is not good. What happens if you change from December to January?

How about this approach:

```
       public bool monthPeriodicityChecker(DateTime start, DateTime end, dateToCheck, periodicity)
        {
            if ((dateToCheck < start) || (dateToCheck > start))
                return false;

            int monthDiff = 0; 
            while (startDate.AddMonths(1) < dateToCheck)
            {
                monthDiff++
                // i'm sure there is a speedier way to calculate the month difference, but this should do for the purpose of this example 
            }

            return (monthDiff) % periodicity == 0;
        };
```

Comment: Hi Anastasiosyal. Your code returns same results as mine code.

Comment: I like @paxdiablo answer more, i've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by generating all of the dates in the range, then see if any of them fall in the same month as `dateToCheck`. First, get the months:

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesInRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, int periodicity)
{
    var current = start;

    do
    {
        yield return current;

        current += TimeSpan.FromMonths(periodicity);
    }
    while(current <= end)
}
```

Then, see if any are in the same month:

```
public bool MonthPeriodicityChecker(DateTime start, DateTime end, DateTime dateToCheck, int periodicity)
{
    return GetDatesInRange(start, end, periodicity).Any(date => date.Month == dateToCheck.Month);
}
```